# Is it possible to hide the real column name from a table during json_encode time?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am encoding a php `array` into `json` format which have data from a table.
My `json_encode` produces result with real column name of that table.I want to use the real `column` name in `php` side and after it encode to `json` format I will like to use some other custom name so, that if some user checks in `.js` file it won't be any problem for me.Below code is the result of `json_encode`.

What is now :-

```
{"result":[{"pals_id":"20","from_user":"hancy061","to_user":"hari061","username":"hancy061"}
```

What I want :-

```
{"result":[{"pid":"20","fu":"hancy061","tu":"hari061","un":"hancy061"}
```

Ya, there isn't any need to show user column name and it seems unsecure too.You guys can see what i want have the json_encode format which I want it to be.Is it possible from `php` side?I mean in `php` side before encoding the `array` into `json` format can we first make custom name of those columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot safely replace these columns on the client-side, because it will be available to a user somehow. If you want a user to never learn how your columns are actually named, you should do this at the server-side.
The most common way is to use SQL aliases.

In your PHP change your SQL query to the following:

```
SELECT pals_id AS pid, from_user AS fu, to_user AS tu, username AS un FROM YourTable ...
```

However, that's a [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and doesn't provide any safety.
If you have an SQL-injection vulnerability, then a hacker will be able to query your data structure from system tables or simply `SELECT *`.

Comment: Security through obscurity is useless. If they can execute a query on the server, then knowing column names makes absolutely no difference. Keep the model relationship the same for your own simplicity.

Comment: It did my work great @yeldar bro :) Thanks for you answer.Ya i will take care about `sql injection` but for now my column name are totally custom made which looks safe comparing to previous.

Answer (score 1):

You could also manually set the array keys in the format you want before encoding, like:

```
foreach ($result as $ind => $r) {
  $result[$ind] = [ // For PHP Versions < 5.4 use 'array('
    "pid" => $r['pals_id'],
    "fu" => $r['from_user'],
    "tu" => $r['to_user'],
    "un" => $r['username'],
  ]; // For PHP Version < 5.4 use ');'
}
```

However you would then have to reverse this if data were to be sent back to the server from the client for updates or something.

If that is needed, then you could set up a map to switch between the two.